# any possible meaning to a "terminal" slash (/)?

Tags: replacement, core-language, symbols, built-in-symbols

I've been directed to the web page

http://functions.wolfram.com/07.31.16.0001.01

The first statement in the formula is

```
HypergeometricPFQ[{Subscript[a, 1], Subscript[a, p]}, {Subscript[b, 
 1], Subscript[b, q]}, 
c z] HypergeometricPFQ[{Subscript[\[Alpha], 1], 
 Subscript[\[Alpha], r]}, {Subscript[\[Beta], 1], 
 Subscript[\[Beta], s]}, d z] == \!\(
\*UnderoverscriptBox[\(\[Sum]\), \(k = 0\), \(\[Infinity]\)]\(
\*SuperscriptBox[\(z\), \(k\)]\ 
\*SubscriptBox[\(c\), \(k\)]\)\) /;
```

Could there be any particular reason there is a slash right before the semi-colon, after the summation, at the end? (I put terminal in quotes in the title, because it typically seems to refer to a computer terminal.)

Comment: If you're not sure what something means, just highlight it inside a notebook and press `F1`

Comment: OK, highlighting it as Mathe172, suggested, indicates that, as one would of course expect, that this indicates Divide. So, it would seem that the slash that I pointed out must have simply been erroneously inserted. I guess I was just being overly-cautious.

Comment: You should select `/;` as one - as indicated by the way Mathematica spaces the characters, this is one operator

Answer (score 2):

*Mathematica* is not Fortran, and doesn't have "statements". Everything is an expression, and *Mathematica* is a system for rewriting expressions by matching patterns and applying rewrite rules. If you don't understand this, you will be profoundly confused by `Mathematica`'s superficial resemblance to a procedural programming language.

`/;` is an infix abbreviation for the `Condition` function, which controls pattern matching.

Comment: Not sure the first paragraph helps explaining anything or has anything to do with the OPs problem

Comment: @Mathe172 The most common source of confusion for *Mathematica* users is failure to understand its fundamental principles. This is not procedural programming. The OP saw a "statement" terminated by `;` because he wasn't expecting a conditional rewrite rule, a very different beast. We tend to gloss over the profound differences between *Mathematica* and programming languages it superficially resembles.

Comment: @Mathe172. It has everything to do with the OP's problem because it is the solution to it. The OP has omitted a large expression of the form `... == ....` that follows the `/;` because the OP thinks `;` is a terminator.